# R: Error when attempting to upload a data frame into SnowFlake table

Tags: r, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, odbc

I have a data frame `DF` in R whose rows I want to append and insert into an existing table in a SnowFlake database. I've established the connection through ODBC:

```
  con <- dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), "SnowFlake" , uid="my_username", pwd="my_password" ,encoding = "latin1")
```

Now, when I try to insert the rows into the table with the below command

```
  dbAppendTable(con, DBI::Id(database="MY_DATABASE", schema="MY_SCHEMA", table="MY_TABLE"),DF,batch_rows=1000)
```

I'm getting the below error:

```
Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1769: 22007: Can't parse 'revenue' as date with format 'AUTO'
```

'revenue' appears as a text field across some rows of the `metric` column which is defined as a string in R. The metric column takes values 'revenue' and 'volume' nothing else. On SnowFlake the `metric` column of the table has format of VARCHAR(255) so it should be able to absorb the values as I'm trying to insert text into a text column.

How may I resolve this issue?

Comment: you may want to provide sample data for the revenue field.   Does the DF have that column as a string or a date?

Comment: @Sorceri thanks I've amended the question to clarify. The column is defined as a string on R which is the intended behavior based on the fields it contains.

Comment: I’m guessing that the columns in your dataframe don’t align with the columns in the table. So it’s not trying to write ‘revenue’ into the metric column, it’s trying to write this into a different column, that is of date datatype